# Is my Turkish Driving License valid in the UK?

Tags: uk, driving, driving-licenses, uk-citizens, turkish-citizens

I have a B category driving licence which I obtained in Turkey. Do you know if my Turkish driving licence is valid in the UK? It was issued both in Turkish and English.

If not, what kind of steps I need to take to make it valid?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it is valid in the UK, according to the [Driver and Vehicle Licensing Agency in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/driving-in-great-britain-on-non-gb-licence):

> If you’ve got a full and valid licence you can drive any small vehicle (eg car or motorcycle) listed on your licence for 12 months from when you last entered Great Britain (GB).

and

> After 12 months you’ll need to apply for a provisional licence and pass the theory and practical driving tests to drive in Great Britain.

Answer (score 2):

If you are driving in a foreign country, you could try getting an International Drivers Permit, which is a translation of your licence into many languages and works in many countries.

Local organisations issue them for a small fee. e.g. I have Ireland The AA issue them.

Comment: This is true but the UK Driver and Vehicle Licensing Agency doesn't seem to mention needing an IDP and, even with an IDP, a foreign license from most non-EU countries (including Turkey) can only be used for up to a year after arrival in the UK.